# pyQt5 scrollbar auto follow

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5

I cannot seem to get the scrollbar in pyqt5 to autofollow and to not autofollow when the y position is not at the end.

I've tried this:

```
    ccursor=self.textCursor()
    sbar=self.verticalScrollBar()
    # get the max value
    csbarval=float(sbar.value())
    maxsbarval=float(sbar.maximum())

    print("sbar value:{}".format(csbarval))
    print("sbar max:{}".format(maxsbarval))

    self.append(data)
    if (float(maxsbarval) > 0.0) and (csbarval/maxsbarval > 0.98):
        ccursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

Is there api in there that can do this automatically?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Right so I had a little think about it in a quiet place, and here's the result:

```
class TEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
 def scrollbarBehaviour(self,data):

  scrollbar=self.verticalScrollBar()
  current_pos=scrollbar.value()
  current_max=scrollbar.maximum()

  at_bottom_of_text=(current_pos>=current_max -4)

  self.append(data)
  if at_bottom_of_text:
   scrollbar.setValue(scrollbar.maximum())
  else:
   scrollbar.setValue(current_pos)
```

The part to note is to figure out if the scrollbar is at the max/end before appending data to the textarea. Also the scrollbar needs to be set explicitly or it will automatically scroll to the end.